# Converting file using `iconv` from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 yields UTF-16LE file

Tags: file-conversion, iconv, gnuwin32

Title.

The command I run is:

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 .\data\schema-utf16le.graphql > .\data\schema-utf8.graphql;
```

However, the generated file `schema-utf8.graphql` is still `UTF-16LE` encoded.

What am I doing wrong?

I am on windows and [installed this version of iconv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/libiconv/1.9.2-1/libiconv-1.9.2-1.exe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been online for a long time and received literally no views nor an answer. Here's how I finally solved the problem.

I made a script for nodejs which performs the conversion:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const schemaFileName = 'data/schema.graphql';

const readContent = fs.readFileSync(schemaFileName, {
  encoding: 'utf16le',
});

const writeContent = (readContent.charAt(0) === '\ufeff')
  ? readContent.substring(1)
  : readContent;

fs.writeFileSync(schemaFileName, writeContent, 'utf8');
```